# Getting ProcedureCallFailed: Failed to invoke procedure : Caused by: org.neo4j.cypher.internal.v3_5.util.SyntaxException:

Tags: python-3.x, neo4j, py2neo, neo4j-apoc

I am trying to dynamically upload node from csv file into neo4j graphdb. So I am developing a script. Here is my code

```
def CreateNodes(filename,label):
    print(filename,label)
    print(type(filename),type(label))
    path=nodesourcefolder+filename
    print(path)
    #filestring=nodesourcefolder+filename
    if(isfile(path)==True):
        print("valid")
        #nodequery="""CALL apoc.periodic.iterate('CALL apoc.load.csv(%s) yield map as row return row','CREATE (p:%s) SET p = row', {batchSize:10000, iterateList:true, parallel:true})"""%(path,label)
        nodequery="""CALL apoc.periodic.iterate('CALL apoc.load.csv("""+path+""") yield map as row return row','CREATE (p:"""+label+""") SET p = row', {batchSize:10000, iterateList:true, parallel:true})"""

        print(nodequery)
    return nodequery   

query=CreateNodes("test.csv","myNode")
graphdriver.run(query)
```

the query variable gives me the value test.csv MyNode

out put

```
<class 'str'> <class 'str'>
/Users/kalyan.admin/NEO4J_HOME/import/test.csv
valid
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate('CALL apoc.load.csv(/Users/kalyan.admin/NEO4J_HOME/import/test.csv) yield map as row return row','CREATE (p:myNode) SET p = row', {batchSize:10000, iterateList:true, parallel:true})
```

when I am going to run graph driver.run(query)

I am getting bellow error

```
**ProcedureCallFailed: Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.periodic.iterate`: Caused by: org.neo4j.cypher.internal.v3_5.util.SyntaxException: Invalid input 'U': expected '*' or '/' (line 1, column 44 (offset: 43))**
```

I have already getting  a string file path name and label  value when I am going to pass  filename, label name into Createnode Function. But my graph driver is not working  to create nodes

Kindly help me to sort this out. I have tried two node query operation one of them is now commented out  but  all those query gives me the same result after running Graphdriver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax issue on your cypher query, the path of the file should be a string.

This is not valid :

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
  'CALL apoc.load.csv(/Users/kalyan.admin/NEO4J_HOME/import/test.csv) yield map as row return row',
  'CREATE (p:myNode) SET p = row', 
  {batchSize:10000, iterateList:true, parallel:true}
)
```

Whereas this is (note the double quotes around the path) :

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
  'CALL apoc.load.csv("/Users/kalyan.admin/NEO4J_HOME/import/test.csv") yield map as row return row',
  'CREATE (p:myNode) SET p = row', 
  {batchSize:10000, iterateList:true, parallel:true}
)
```

Comment: thanks for replying but  my path variable is already a string 
/Users/kalyan.admin/NEO4J_HOME/import/test.csv
Type <class 'str'>
could you kindly elaborate this. How could I  insert path parameter in my call apoc query. I have also tried string formatter %S   in my code

Comment: yes your path is a string in your python code, but not in the cypher query ! You should have something like that  `CALL apoc.load.csv("%s")`

Comment: thank you  it worked. I did %s instead "%s" before . "%s" worked here :)